# Importing data to Master File that has a changing name

Tags: vba, excel, import, excel-formula

I'm trying to copy and paste data from a selected workbook into my master file. One main problem I'm having is getting back to the master file, the reason being is that the name of the master file changes each month to whatever month it's being run in e.g. "March Master File" for this month "April Master File" when I run it next month. I have tried getting back to the file by referencing a file path but it doesn't work e.g. "Windows(TEMPLATEFile).Activate". Any suggestions on if there's an easier way of writing this and not having to refer to a file path?

This is what I go so far:

```
Sub ImportRepurchData()

    Dim combinedBook As Workbook
    Dim filter As String
    Dim caption As String
    Dim combinedFilename As String
    Dim combinedWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

    TEMPLATEFile = Sheets("Dynamic").Range("ImportRepurch")
    ' Open Source Data

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
    caption = "Please Select an input file"
    combinedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    Set combinedWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(combinedFilename)
    ' Paste Source Data into original workbook

    Range("P4:P100000,AL4:AL100000").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows(TEMPLATEFile).Activate

    Sheets("Input Sched-Unsched Split").Select
    Range("B9:B100000,C9:C100000").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    combinedWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to have got the hang of referencing Workbooks, why not `Set` the initial workbook to a object and then `objectname.Activate` ?

Comment: PS. You've `Dim`med `CombinedBook` - yet you don't use it.

Comment: @CLR I think the issue is **not** identifying the workbook later in the code. The issue is identifying the workbook **to** `Set` to begin with. Each month, it's got a different name before the code runs. Kieran1995 needs to be able to tell vba which workbook is the master, **before** being able to `Set` it to a variable.

Comment: You could be right @Mistella, but the question is a little vague on how many sheets are even open at the start of the code, which one is running the code etc. Jen's suggestion that loops through each book name looking for a pattern might be the solution or just `Set`ting the right book at the start could also. It depends on the set up.

Comment: @CLR Thanks for the advice. I've just used 'ThisWorkbook' to get back to the masterfile as that's the workbook which is running the file. Simple solution which I should have known, all good learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the code from within your masterfile, you could just use 
    Thisworkbook
instead of 
    Application.Workbooks(someIndexOrName)

Thisworkbook is always the workbook which is running tje code, even when it is an add-in (XLAM).

If this is not the case, you could write a function which identifies your workbook, e.g. based on whether a sheet with a special name (or code name) exists. Maybe even multiple sheet. Then you could loop over Application.Workbooks until you find your masterfile

Comment: Thank you, this was useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

The other point is that this is causing you problems:

```
Range("P4:P100000,AL4:AL100000").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows(TEMPLATEFile).Activate

Sheets("Input Sched-Unsched Split").Select
Range("B9:B100000,C9:C100000").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

When you can achieve the same effect with

```
 combinedWorkbook.range("P4:P100000").copy targetworkbook.worksheets(""Input Sched-Unsched Split").range("B9")
 combinedWorkbook.range("al4:al100000").copy targetworkbook.worksheets("Input Sched-Unsched Split").range("c9")
```

Never use select or activate in VBA

Comment: Thanks. I've used ThisWorkbook to get back to my masterfile but the code seems to fall over when using you're suggested code. The error is Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. Any suggestions with reagrds to this?

Comment: @Kieran1995 **Note:** There's an extra quotation mark in the first line of the second block of code. If you copied and pasted as is, that would cause some errors.

Comment: @Mistella spotted that - the error occurs after I changed that

Comment: @Kieran1995 It might be because `combinedWorkbook.range` doesn't have a worksheet reference, such as `combinedWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").range`. I'm not sure workbooks have range objects; they may just have sheet objects.

Comment: Sorry, missed that - you need to add the sheet name So it should be combinedWorkbook.Sheets("name of sheet").Range(2P4:P100000").copy etc.